# Drag function won't allow desired selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, lightbox

I'm using the below code to make the images on my site draggable, but I can not choose the selector I wish to use. Although the images are draggable while using '.photo', it uses a bounding box with a larger size than the image and I would rather use 'img' or '.img1' & '.img2'.

Also since I started using this code the *lightbox* function is triggered every time I release the image instead of only on solid clicks.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.photo').drag(function( ev, dd ){
        $( this ).css({
            top: dd.offsetY,
            left: dd.offsetX
        });
    });
});
```

*I have used `Draggable` for this effect but that led to a weird issue in Chrome/Safari that I couldn't solve so I chose a new approach.*

**EDIT**
Here's the HTML used for each image ('.img1' can also be '.img2' on images)

```
 <div class="photo"><a href="http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/1/images/full/001.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img class="img1" src="http://www.coreytegeler.com/jb/1/images/001.png"/></a></div>
```

Comment: would you please add the elemnt html?

Comment: So what is your problem here?

Comment: Added the HTML element

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko do you not understand the problems I listed?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the drag behavior to the item you want to be the selector, then use the function to move the image.

You are probably getting the lightbox triggering on every drag because it's recording a mousedown/mouseup event sequence and the standard override from the drag is getting disabled since you have a custom drag event.

Comment: I've tried changing the selector, that's where the problem is, nothing besides '.photo' is working. But I'm also kind of new to this so I may be doing something wrong.

How can I enable the override?